# Modifying a form's fields after user authentication

Tags: django

I have a view that inherits from `UpdateView` and `UserPassesTestMixin`. Two types of user can access it - either a superuser or a normal one. I determine which one it is in `test_func()` and store the result in `self.superuser`. Now I want to modify the displayed form depending on the level of the user (namely disable almost all fields in the form if the current user is not a superuser, otherwise leave them all enabled). Which view method should I override to modify the view's form (in this case disable the necessary fields)? Or is this idea wrong and I should approach this differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data you need to recognize the user to the form and in your form, you can get the data in the `__init__` then you can change the `self.fields` in there to reflect the type of user.

Check this example that removes the `ReadOnly` to the field `superuser_field` if the form is instantiated for a superuser.

```
  class MyForm(forms.Form):

  def __init__(self, is_superuser=False, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_superuser:
        self.fields['superuser_field'].disabled = False
```

In your code you can, if I understood correctly:

```
def yourview(...):
    # ...
    myform = MyForm(is_superuser=self.superuser)
    # ....
```